# Find $\tan(π/16)+\tan(5π/16)+\tan(9π/16)+\tan(13π/16)$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I had to calculate $\tan(π/16)+\tan(5π/16)+\tan(9π/16)+\tan(13π/16)$

I tried writing $π/16=x$ and then writing the sum as $\tan x+\tan(9x-4x)+\tan9x+\tan(9x+4x)$ and then simplifying using $\tan(x+y)$ and $\tan(x-y)$ but it didn't simplify to anything, can anybody please give a hint on how should I approach this.

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557360/a-trigonometric-equation

Comment: $\tan4x=\tan(m\pi+y)$ Here $y=\pi/4$

Comment: Put $n=4$ and then $\theta=\dfrac\pi4$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a=\tan(\frac{\pi}{16})+\tan(\frac{5\pi}{16})+\tan(\frac{9\pi}{16})+\tan(\frac{13\pi}{16})\\=
\tan(\frac{\pi}{16})+\tan(\frac{5\pi}{16})+\tan(\frac{1\pi}{16}+\frac{\pi}{2})+\tan(\frac{5\pi}{16}+\frac{\pi}{2})\\=\\
\tan(\frac{\pi}{16})-\cot(\frac{\pi}{16})+\tan(\frac{5\pi}{16})-\cot(\frac{5\pi}{16})\\=?$$
now let me note that $\color{red} {2\cot(2x)=\cot x- \tan x}\tag{1}$ so 
$$a=-(-\tan(\frac{\pi}{16})+\cot(\frac{\pi}{16})-\tan(\frac{5\pi}{16})+\cot(\frac{5\pi}{16}))\\=
-(2\cot(\frac{2\pi}{16})+2\cot(\frac{10\pi}{16}))\\=$$can you go on  ?
$$a=-2(\cot(\frac{\pi}{8})+\cot(\frac{5\pi}{8}))\\=-2(\cot(\frac{\pi}{8})+\cot(\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2}))\\\text{from formula (1)}\\
-2(\cot(\frac{\pi}{8})-\tan(\frac{\pi}{8}))\\=-2(2\cot(2(\frac{\pi}{8}))\\=-4$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\tan\left(x+\pi\right) = \tan(x).$$
If $x=\frac{3\pi}{16}$, and $y=\frac{2\pi}{16}$, then $x+y = ?$ and $x-y=?$.